# Create separate Python dictionary from nested Json

Tags: python

I have a data in below format, which is nested Json. I am looking to create a dictionary based on values of nested json.

Json Data in below format

```
data = {
    "0": {
        "0": "Accomplishments:",
        "1": "Testing"
    },
    "1": {
        "0": "Priorities:",
        "1": "Priorities value"
    },
    "2": {
        "0": "agenda:",
        "1": "3 months"
    }
}
```

Expected outcome is as below

```
{
    "Accomplishments:" : "Testing",
    "Priorities:" : "Testing",
    "agenda:" : "3 months"
}
```

Comment: The problem is how to track your "Priorities" value, The output shows "Testing". but how ?

Comment: Its just the value fetched from an table.

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = {}
for subdict in data.values():
    result[subdict["0"]] = subdict["1"]
print(result)
```

Or with dict comprehension:

```py
result = {subdict["0"]: subdict["1"] for subdict in data.values()}
print(result)
```

Result: `{'Accomplishments:': 'Testing', 'Priorities:': 'Priorities value', 'agenda:': '3 months'}`

To dump as json string, do `result_as_json = json.dumps(result)`

Comment: Hi h4z3, thank you for the help. New learning for me.